# How do I view number of times the LIKE button is clicked each day

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have created several custom LIKE buttons for different pages of my website. I need to trace back how many daily click / LIKEs for last month.

Is there any APIs/ FB Insights that support display of such statistics / analytic data?

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks a like button, in addition to sending the request to Facebook through whatever SDK you are using, you can also send an Ajax request to a page on your own server. This page would contain code to increment a counter of the clicked like button in a database.

For example, let's say you have this code on your page:

```
<script>
function sendToDatabase(id)
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "handler.php?id="+id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<a onclick="sendToFacebook(); sendToDatabase(this.id);" id="like23">LIKE</a>
```

Then, the contents of handler.php:

```
<?php
$db = sqlite_open("db.sqlite");
$query = "UPDATE likes SET count=count+1 WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";
sqlite_query($db, $query);
?>
```

This is assuming you are using JavaScript, PHP, SQLite, and you already have a table set up in the SQLite database, "db.sqlite". Your table could be as simple as two columns - id and count.